# TypeError: base.contacts is undefined - how can i define it?

Tags: javascript

Receiving the above error in reference to the line `for ( var i = 0; i < base.contacts.length; i++) {` and can't figure out how to resolve. Below is the relevant code section

```
 synckolab.addressbookTools.createTBirdObject = function (base, cards) {
    var card = null;
    if (base.type === "contact") {
        card = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/addressbook/cardproperty;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIAbCard);
    } else if (base.type === "maillist") {
    card = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/addressbook/directoryproperty;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIAbDirectory);
    card.isMailList = true;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

// for a mailing list add the entries
    if (base.type === "maillist") {
    card.dirName = this.getCardProperty(base, "DisplayName");
    if (this.haveCardProperty(base, "NickName")) {
        card.listNickName = this.getCardProperty(base, "NickName");
    }
    if (this.haveCardProperty(base, "Notes")) {
        card.description = this.getCardProperty(base, "Notes");
    }
    // fill the list
    for ( var i = 0; i < base.contacts.length; i++) {
        var listCard = cards.get(this.getUID(base.contacts[i]));
        card.addressLists.appendElement(listCard, false);
    }
} else {
    // go through all elements of base
    for ( var field in base) {
        // skip our own stuff TODO: handle mailing lists!
        if (field !== "type" && field !== "synckolab" && field !== "ts" && field !== "contacts" && field !== "isMailList") {
            // copy the property from base to card
            this.setCardProperty(card, field, this.getCardProperty(base, field));
        }
    }
}

return card;
```

};

Comment: And how do you call that function? `base` is a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base` is a parameter you hand over to the function which is supposed to be an object having (at least) the following properties:

```
type
contact
```

Obviously it is missing the `contact` property, which again should be an array. So you should take a look at the object which you are handing over to the function.

To fix this problem temporarily you could do:

```
if (base.contacts){
    for ( var i = 0; i < base.contacts.length; i++) {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

However to really fix the problem, you should take a look at the code, where the function is called and examine, how the object which you hand to the function is constructed. Do a

```
console.log(base);
```

to take a closer look at the object.